# Math aid Needed: Scaling an Arduino analog input to be -1 to 1

Tags: math, arduino, scaling

The Arduino map() function does not work for this problem, and HAVE scoured the 'net for examples but am still coming up at a loss. My 'math-brain' is ded!!  :-(

I have a pot going into an Arduino analog input produces a range of 170 to 1000.  I'd like to scale that to a range of -1 to 1 to simulate a commercial joystick that is being replaced.

There is an Arduino Micro reading the pots and sending the data by serial to Processing.  This all works - just can't get the -1 to 1 range to send out.

A formula to do this would be a HUGE help!
=Alan R.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear interpolation to do the magic. If x is the input and y is your desired output, the following relation will work out:

> (y-1)/(x-1000) = (1-(-1))/(1000-170) = 1/415
>
> So basically, y = 1 + (x-1000)/415